# Format Flag Conversion Mismatch Exception

Tags: java, printf

Write a program that inputs the name, quantity, and price of three items. The name may contain spaces. Output a bill with a tax rate of 6.25%. All prices should be output to two decimal places. The bill should be formatted in columns with 30 characters for the name, 10 characters for the quantity, 10 characters for the price, and 10 characters for the total. Sample input and output are shown as follows:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectLab {

    public static final double SALES_TAX = 8.625;

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String item1, item2, item3;

        int quantity1, quantity2, quantity3;

        double price1, price2, price3;

        //Input for the first Item
        System.out.println("Input the name of item 1: ");
        item1 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Input quantity of item 1: ");
        quantity1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input price of item 1: ");
        price1 = input.nextDouble();

        String junk = input.nextLine(); //Junk Line
        //Input for the second Item
        System.out.println("Input name of item 2: ");
        item2 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Input quantity of item 2: ");
        quantity2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input price of item 2: ");
        price2 = input.nextDouble();

        String junk2 = input.nextLine(); //Junk line 2
        //Input for the third item
        System.out.println("Input name of item 3: ");
        item3 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Input quantity of item 3: ");
        quantity3 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input price of item 3: ");
        price3 = input.nextDouble();

        double subtotal1 = price1 * quantity1;
        double subtotal2 = price2 * quantity2;
        double subtotal3 = price3 * quantity3;

        System.out.println("Your bill: ");
        System.out.println("Item      Quantity    Price    Total");
        System.out.println(item1 + "    " + quantity1 + "   " + price1 + "  " + subtotal1 );
        System.out.println(item2 + "    " + quantity2 + "   " + price2 + "  " + subtotal2 );
        System.out.println(item3 + "    " + quantity3 + "   " + price3 + "  " + subtotal3 );

        double finalSubtotal = (subtotal1 + subtotal2 + subtotal3);

        System.out.printf("Subtotal %.2f          \n" , finalSubtotal);

        double tax = (finalSubtotal / SALES_TAX); 

        System.out.printf("8.265% Sales tax %.2f\n        ", tax);

        double total = tax + finalSubtotal;

        System.out.printf("Total %.2f                     ", total);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Input the name of item 1: 
Gummi Bears
Input quantity of item 1: 
10
Input price of item 1: 
1.29
Input name of item 2: 
Monster Energy
Input quantity of item 2: 
3
Input price of item 2: 
2.97
Input name of item 3: 
Ruffles Chips
Input quantity of item 3: 
20
Input price of item 3: 
1.49
Your bill: 
Item      Quantity    Price    Total
Gummi Bears 10  1.29    12.9
Monster Energy  3   2.97    8.91
Ruffles Chips   20  1.49    29.8
Subtotal    51.61         
Exception in thread "main" java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = s, Flags =  
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failMismatch(Formatter.java:4298)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkBadFlags(Formatter.java:2997)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkGeneral(Formatter.java:2955)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2725)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at ProjectLab.main(ProjectLab.java:65)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your % with another %

```
System.out.printf("8.265%% Sales tax %.2f\n        ", tax);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `String.format(..)` at your last 3 outputs.

Try this

```
// also "\n" can be replaced with println
System.out.println(String.format("Subtotal %.2f          " , finalSubtotal));
// also escape the first % sign
System.out.println(String.format("8.265 %% Sales tax %.2f        ", tax));
```

[More information for string fromatting here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: There's no need for the space between `8.265` and `%%`.